# I gor error of tensor object has no attribute compile

Tags: keras, model, tf.keras

this is keras tensorflow based model

```
base_model = VGG16(include_top = False, input_shape=(32, 32, 3))
base_model.layers.pop()
base_model.outputs = [base_model.layers[-1].output]
last = base_model.outputs[0]
x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1))(last)
x = Conv2D(filters=1024, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
model = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x) ## nb_classes=5
```

Then I try to compile it

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

then following error showed up

> ----> 6 model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
>         7               optimizer=optimizer,
>         8               metrics=['accuracy'])
>
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: Only a Model instance has a compile method, you didn't build a model, that's why it errors correctly.

Comment: Have a read at https://keras.io/models/model/ how to create a model using Keras API